# How can I get the authentification dialog programatically?

Tags: bash, authentication, gksudo

Instead of using **gksudo** in a bash script, I want to invoke the **authenticate dialog** ( as in screenshot) instead. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks.

[image: Ubuntu Authentication dialog]

Comment: Isn't that dialog invoked by `gksu` itself or `policykit` (for example synaptic).

Comment: Not at all. it's not gksu (gksudo is somehow an alias for gksu in Ubuntu). But policykit is from what I recall a keyword in what I am looking for. Of course, when you run synaptic without root privilege, it prompts you with the authenticate dialog I am interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Well. 'just found the man page in Ubuntu wiki.
Actually it's **pkexec**

pkexec --$USER  somepackage

[image: Solution]

Thanks @Uri Herrera . You were the trigger.